# Как сделать textarea в jinja2?

Tags: html, python, flask, textarea, jinja2

Делаю проект на Flask.
Я передаю в шаблон форму и могу отображать её с помощью шаблонизатора jinja2 так:

```
{{ form.right_answer }}
```

В таком случае после генерации появится тег input. Что нужно сделать, чтобы вместо input был тег textarea?

Comment: Jinja2 тут абсолютно ни при чём, обращайтесь к документации вашего объекта form

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979548/how-to-render-my-textarea-with-wtforms

```
# Из-за того, что ответ не может быть короче 30 символов, 
# приходится писать данное бессмысленное предложение.
```